# Adding facebook like button to webpage created in microsoft frontpage 2003

Tags: facebook-like, frontpage

I am unable to add like button to my frontpage website when I insert the code it gives me an error message stating can not open page file, I attempted to upload as HTML and iFrame still no luck. Help

Comment: For one thing, Microsoft Office SharePoint Designer is the successor to FrontPage, and is free. You might want to upgrade. Also, it would help if you gave details of what you did and what error you got.

Answer (score 0):

Use iframe embedded  in code. Make sure you the right characters and character breaks in the URL String.

```
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3a%2f%2fwww.URL.com&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;font=tahoma&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=20"
            scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"
            style="border: none; height: 20px; width: 90px; overflow: hidden;">
   </iframe>
```